# How can I initialize variable before each test using kotlin-test framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I'm trying to find a way to set up variable before each test. Just like the  @Before method in Junit. Go through the doc from kotlin-test, I found that I can use interceptTestCase() interface. But unfortunately, the code below will trigger exception:

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property text has not been initialized`

```
class KotlinTest: StringSpec() {
lateinit var text:String
init {
    "I hope variable is be initialized before each test" {
        text shouldEqual "ABC"
    }

    "I hope variable is be initialized before each test 2" {
        text shouldEqual "ABC"
    }
}

override fun interceptTestCase(context: TestCaseContext, test: () -> Unit) {
    println("interceptTestCase()")
    this.text = "ABC"
    test()
}
}
```

Am I in the wrong way to use interceptTestCase()?
Thank you very much~

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution is to add below statement in test case:
`override val oneInstancePerTest = false`

The root cause is that oneInstancePerTest is true by default(although it's false in kotlin test doc), which means every test scenario will run in the different instances.

In the case in question,
The initializing `interceptTestCase` method ran in instance *A*, set *text* to *ABC*. Then the test case ran in instance *B* without `interceptTestCase`.

For more detail, there is an open issue in GitHub:
https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/174

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the `text` variable.
init called first when you create an object for a class.

You are calling `text shouldEqual "ABC"` in `init` block in your code, that time there will be no value in a `text` variable.

Your function `interceptTestCase(context: TestCaseContext, test: () -> Unit)` only can be called after the `init` block.

Initialize the text at the constructor itself like below code, so you won't get this error or make some alternative.

```
class KotlinTest(private val text: String): StringSpec()
```

Comment: Actually this is not the reason. `text shouldEqual "ABC"` is not called in `init` block, lambda containing `text shouldEqual "ABC"` is only created there, not run.